# Extract the latest date in the given array using GatewayScript

Tags: javascript, xml, string, date, datetime

> Below is the sample incoming XML request and i need to iterate all the dates and extract the latest updated date using gatewayScript in output.

```
<rsp:response
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:rsp="rsp.com/employee/Response/v30"
xmlns:res="res.com/Member/details/v1">
<rsp:period>
    <res:Period>
        <rsp:date>2020-07-06T19:38:39</rsp:date>
    </res:Period>
</rsp:period>
<rsp:period>
    <res:Period>
        <rsp:date>2020-08-07T20:38:39</rsp:date>
    </res:Period>
</rsp:period>
<rsp:period>
    <res:Period>
        <rsp:date>2020-05-06T19:18:39</rsp:date>
    </res:Period>
</rsp:period>
```

</rsp:response>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what your question is, hopefully this helps.

You can use the [*DOMParser*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) constructor to create a DOM parser, then turn the XML into a document. From there, use DOM methods to get the required elements and extract the dates, then iterate over them to find the latest.

E.g. the following gets the latest date using lexical comparison, which works because the dates are in ISO 8601 format.

```js
let xml = `
  <rsp:response
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:rsp="rsp.com/employee/Response/v30"
    xmlns:res="res.com/Member/details/v1">
    <rsp:period>
      <res:Period>
        <rsp:date>2020-07-06T19:38:39</rsp:date>
      </res:Period>
    </rsp:period>
    <rsp:period>
      <res:Period>
        <rsp:date>2020-08-07T20:38:39</rsp:date>
      </res:Period>
    </rsp:period>
    <rsp:period>
      <res:Period>
        <rsp:date>2020-05-06T19:18:39</rsp:date>
      </res:Period>
    </rsp:period>
  </rsp:response>`;

let parser = new DOMParser();
let doc = parser.parseFromString(xml, 'application/xml');
let nodes = Array.from(doc.getElementsByTagName('rsp:date'));
let dates = nodes.map(node => node.textContent);
let latestDate = dates.reduce((latest, date) => date < latest? latest : date);

console.log(latestDate);
```

There is some overlap in DOM methods for HTML and XML documents, especially with the [*DOM Core*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_object_model/Using_the_W3C_DOM_Level_1_Core) methods such as *getElementsByTagName*. You can also use [*XPath*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath), but that's a whole new language to learn and support might be patchy depending on the environment you're using.

Comment: Thank you for the response and code is working.